# wp_post_insert HTML in post_content

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to use wp_post_insert function to create posts/pages from my HTML pages.

So far I've got:

```
$html = file_get_contents($dir . $data['url']);

$post = array(
        'post_content'  => $html,
        'post_name'     => sanitize_title_with_dashes($data['title']), 
        'post_title'    => $data['title'],
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type'     => $data['type'], 
);  
$post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
```

However this does not seems to be working as post_content is always empty. I've tried different sanitation functions, but none of them are working.

HTML code is read into $html variable, but I guess the problem comes because its multiple lines.

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Please clarify: are you saying that `$html` is not filled in by `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: can you verify that $dir . $data['url'] points to a valid file, and that file_get_contents() is actually returning anything? if so try doing $html = str_replace(array("\n","\r"),"",$html);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive found that the files that I am reading were encoded with UCS2 encoding - file_get_contents returns special characters which looks good in browser (browser has its own character encoding), but not good for WP.

The solution was to reencode HTML files into UTF-8 ones.

Answer (score 0):

Trick the function into thinking that the input has already been sanitized with the `filter` attribute:

```
$post = array(
        'post_content'  => $html,
        'post_name'     => sanitize_title_with_dashes($data['title']), 
        'post_title'    => $data['title'],
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type'     => $data['type'], 
        'filter' => true 
);
```